# Image is not loading from JSON file?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
I need to fill the footer with JSON data stored in a file.I created custom directive called "photo" and controller named "myController".I am using isolated scope to bind controller and directive.But I don't know why json data is not displaying.please help me out.

HTML page
<div class="footer">    
<div ng-controller="myController">
<photo customers="customer">
</photo>
</div>
```

The above HTML is my index page.
    Controller
This is the controller I am using for reading JSON data from a  file.

```
app.controller("myController", function($scope, $http) {
 $http.get('tetra.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {          $scope.customer = data;  
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    });
});
custom directive
app.directive('photo', function() {
  return {
      restrict:'AEC',
      scope:{
          customers : '='
      },
    templateUrl: 'customer.html',
    css:'foo.css'
  };
});
```

customer.html

{{customer.footer.imageFile}}

Comment: Do you receive the JSON correctly in your $http.get? In your dev tools do you see the request to tetra.json and is it successful?

Comment: yes I can see values through console.log()

Comment: <div data-ng-repeat="customer in customers">
<img src="{{customer.footer.imageFile}}" width=customer.footer.imageWidth}} height={{customer.footer.imageHeight}} align={{customer.footer.imageLayout}}>
</div>
this is my customer.html page

Comment: You have to use ng-src but I assume none of the values are actually coming through?